# Running external program from my python program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a clock GUI program that I need to run another python program from but my clock stops or I get a defunct process when I close the client program and I need the parent program to continue to run. What I've tried is:

```
os.system(run my program)  "This stops the parent clock"
os.popen(run my program)  "This stops the parent clock"
subprocess.call(run my program)  "This stops the parent clock"
subprocess.Popen(run my program)  "This works but when the client is closed goes defunct"
```

Is there a way to run my external program without stopping my clock and not leaving a defunct process?

Comment: Have you tried `os.startfile()`?

Comment: This just gives me a error 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using subprocess module with a nohup attached?

Something like this should stop the sigint from quiting the child process

```
import subprocess
import os

def run_process(self,cmd):
    subprocess.Popen("nohup " + cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', 
                     stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                     stderr=open('logfile.log', 'a'),
                     preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

run_process('ls -R ~') # Or whatever you are trying to run
```

Comment: Thanks Joe but same problem.

Comment: I'd look into forking then, I've had a quick look for a guide , this was the first result. You'll need a read up http://www.python-course.eu/forking.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me:

import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)

This works!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run different programs at the same time, you can use threads for each subprocess.

import threading

t = threading.Thread(target=myprogram)
t.start()

Comment: Thanks Lastre but same problem